# Update values in column

Tags: sql, datatable, sql-update

I have following SQL-Table:

```
A   B  C   D
"1" 2  3  "4" 
"2" 4  4  "5"
"4" 1  6  "9"
```

I would like to remove the ""

So my result should look like this:

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4
2  4  4  5
4  1  6  9
```

Comment: `update table set a = replace(a,'"',''), d = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple `UPDATE` with `REPLACE()` function as

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET A = REPLACE(A, '"', ''),
    B = REPLACE(B, '"', ''),
    C = REPLACE(C, '"', ''),
    D = REPLACE(D, '"', '')
--Where conditions if needed
```

Comment: One of my column name is : Bla in Bla I always get an error here

Comment: @ProgrammJüngling02 You didn't include that in the question, yet you can just wrap it in brackets as `[Bla in Bla]`. BTW what's the DBMS you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below script..

```
select replace(A,'"',''),B,C,replace(D,'"','') from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table_Name SET col_name = REPLACE(col_name, '"', '');
```

Comment: One of my column name is : Bla in Bla I always get an error here –

Answer (score 0):

Hi ProgrammJüngling02,

Use the following to check that you are happy with the result:

```
SELECT REPLACE(A,'"','') A, B, C, REPLACE(D,'"','') D
```

Use the following to actually remove the "s:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET A = REPLACE(A,'"',''), D = REPLACE(D,'"','')
```